# Magento 2 css from php

Tags: php, css, magento2.4

Who can tell me how to change the link from PHP.

```
$this->pageConfig->addPageAsset('')
```

I already tried but not working.

```
$this->getUrl('https://...')
```

Thank you!

Comment: you want to redirect on another page?

Comment: Can you specify what you are try to access

Comment: i want to add my cdn css link in this php file, not same domain. @GohilRajesh

Comment: Yes, is my cdn link. @DhirenVasoya

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code to add `css` file on your `phtml` file.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="YOURCSSURL" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I would try to add this method on your block template :

```
protected function _prepareLayout()
```

And then customise your metadata as you want in there. But this is the same thing as updating directly the phtml file as mentionned by @Dhiren Vasoya

Answer (score 0):

**To include an external CSS file from xml**, add

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/frontend-dev-guide/css-topics/css-themes.html

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <css src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css"  src_type="url" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"  />
    </head>
</page>
```

**To include an external CSS file from php**

Step 1 – Create a block class in your module

```
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template;
 
class Head extends Template
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\View\Asset\Repository
     */
    protected $assetRepository;
 
    /**
     * Header constructor.
     * @param Template\Context $context
     * @param array $data
     */
    public function __construct(
        Template\Context $context,
        array $data = []
    )
    {
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
        $this->assetRepository = $context->getAssetRepository();
    }
 
    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getUrlCSS()
    {
        $asset_repository = $this->assetRepository;
        $asset  = $asset_repository->createAsset('URL to External Source');
        $url    = $asset->getUrl();
         
        return $url;
    }
}
```

Step 2 – Create corresponding phtml for the class created in Step 1

```
$url = $block->getUrlCSS();
if ($url):
    echo '<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="'.$block->getUrlCSS().'" />'
endif;
```

Step 3 – Create layout xml file to call the above phtml file in the head section of your website under